# MongoDB - Aggregate 2 finds in one single projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some trouble to build a query in mongodb 3.6 that aggregate(?) some data together.

I have a collections named "Roles", where inside i store my roles and the users linked to that role:

```
{
 _Id: ObjectId('..'),
 RoleName: admin,
 Users: [.. array of users ..]
},
{
 _Id: ObjectId('..'),
 RoleName: others,
 Users: [.. array of users ..]
},
{
 _Id: ObjectId('..'),
 RoleName: users,
 Users: [.. array of users ..]
}
```

I searched a lot about projection and find operator, without success.
I want to achive something like this:

```
{
 _Id: ObjectId('a'),
 RoleName: admin,
 Users: [.. array of users ..],
 AvailableRoles: [
     {
         _Id: ObjectId('c'),
         RoleName: users
     },
     {
         _Id: ObjectId('b'),
         RoleName: others
     }]
},
{
 _Id: ObjectId('b'),
 RoleName: others,
 Users: [.. array of users ..],
 AvailableRoles: [
      {
         _Id: ObjectId('c'),
         RoleName: users
      },
      {
          _Id: ObjectId('a'),
          RoleName: admin
      }]
},
{
 _Id: ObjectId('c'),
 RoleName: users,
 Users: [.. array of users ..],
 AvailableRoles: [
     {
         _Id: ObjectId('b'),
         RoleName: others
     },
     {
         _Id: ObjectId('a'),
         RoleName: admin
     }]
}
```

"AvailableRoles" as you can see, contains the other entities of roles except himself.

Is it possible within one single query?

Greetings

Comment: If you want to "achieve" it, then you might just start by explaining what the output is supposed to be. What are the roles for populating the content into `AvailableRoles`. Is it really just supposed to be "everything else in the collection except myself"? If so, then what is the point? If not, then please explain.

Comment: It's everything else in the collection. I just need a query as reference for my project in C#. I will use this "projection" in mongodb driver for mapping purpose. PS: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Well if the collection is small enough to even allow it then I probably would not bother with any "query" and simply attach the whole output list to each document in the list and filter out the current one. Or if you really must engage in such "malarkey" on the server, then the [non-correlated form of `$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#uncorrelated-subquery) is the best bet.

Comment: And that is simply `{ "$lookup": { "from": "same_collection", "let": { "_id": "$_id" }, "pipeline": [{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$ne": ["$_id", "$$_id"] } }}], "as": "AvailableRoles" }}`

Comment: So, if i undestood, you will going to get all roles, and process them server-side in a `foreach role` instead database-side. Why this choise? I will read some documentation on `$lookup` operator for understand better your answer.

Comment: Why? Because for any "real size database" of the type we would typically use a database for, you simply could not ask MongoDB to return :"the rest of the collection" embedded in an array inside "every document in the collection" as it would most certainly break the BSON limit. For the trivially small amount of data you must be talking about to even consider this, you may as well just pull it all into memory and very quickly and efficiently work with it there.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Can you make an answer so i can pin it as "Solution"?